# Pytables Value Error (rank of the appended object and "..."EArray differ)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pytables

I am trying to use pytables to store my images dataset. I am using Earray to append each image as it is read. The dimensions of my Earray and image are same(except for the first, along which appending is done). I am using the following code:

```
atom = Atom.from_dtype(np.dtype(np.uint32,(278,278,1)))
i=0
for <read each image from folder using os into img>:
    im = cv2.imread(img.path,0)
    im = np.expand_dims(im,2) #this is because keras needs 3d images and grayscale images are 2d
    if not i:
        X = data.create_earray(dataGroup,"X",atom,(0,)+im.shape,chunkshape=(20,20,20,1))
   X.append(np.expand_dims(im,0)) #as appending require same dim.
   i=1
```

But still when I run the code, it gives my ValueError saying the my object rank is 1 and X rank is 4. How is that possible when I am assigning X size using im. I even tried printing shape of im, it gives (278,278,1). So, what is the problem? I am using Pytables for first time, so dont know them in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a second answer with a more complicated write method plus an `EArray.read` example. Frankly, I prefer my simpler method (above) to create the EArray with `obj=` defined, and let Pytables handle the data structures. However, if you prefer to manage this yourself, see example 2 (below). Key items to note:

- Atom definition has 4 dimensions, with 0 axis set to zero (defines
  the direction that will be extended).
- `im = np.expand_dims(im,0)` is done until AFTER `im.shape` is referenced in the
  definition of the EArray shape at creation.

[UPDATED CODE BELOW]

```
import tables as tb, numpy as np
data = tb.open_file("image_data1.h5", mode='w')
dataGroup = data.create_group(data.root, 'MyData')
MyAtom = tb.Atom.from_dtype(np.dtype(np.uint32,(0,278,278,1)))

im = np.arange(278*278).reshape((278,278))
im = np.expand_dims(im,2)

X = data.create_earray(dataGroup,"X", MyAtom, (0,)+im.shape)

im = np.expand_dims(im,0)
X.append( im )

print ('flavor =', X.flavor )
print ('dim=', X.ndim, ', rows = ', X.nrows)

im = np.arange(278*278,278*278+278*278).reshape((278,278))
im = np.expand_dims(im,2)
im = np.expand_dims(im,0)

X.append( im )

print ('dim=', X.ndim, ', rows = ', X.nrows)

data.close()
```

Here are the lines you need to read the data from EArray X (with a couple of `print` statements to verify values in the corners). This should work so long as the EArray flavor is Numpy (as it is in my example). You can also use the `out=` parameter to specify a NumPy array to receive the output data. There are other methods to access EArray data, including `.iterrows()` to iterate, and `.__getitem__()` to slice with fancy indexing. Read the Pytables documentation if you want to do any of these.

```
Y_1 = X.read( 0 )
print (Y_1[0,0,0])
print (Y_1[-1,-1,-1])

Y_2 = X.read( 1 )
print (Y_2[0,0,0])
print (Y_2[-1,-1,-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, note that you don't have to create the EArray before you load the first image dataset. Pytables is smart enough to determine the atom and shape definition from the first object.
It was hard for me to exercise your code without a complete example and your data. So, I created a very simple example that uses `np.arange()` to create a couple of `(278,278)` image arrays, then extends them in the 2 and 0 directions. Hopefully this mimics the data you are trying to load to the EArray. The 2 Pytables functions (`file.create_earray` and `earray.append`) create 2 rows of data, 1 for each "image". After running, open `image_data1.h5` with HDFView and inspect the data.
Maybe this will help you understand how to load your images to HDF5 Earrays:

```
import tables as tb, numpy as np
data = tb.open_file("image_data1.h5", mode='w')
dataGroup = data.create_group(data.root, 'MyData')

im = np.arange(278*278).reshape((278,278))
im = np.expand_dims(im,2)
im = np.expand_dims(im,0)

X = data.create_earray( dataGroup,"X",obj=im )

print ('dim=', X.ndim, ', rows = ', X.nrows)

im = np.arange(278*278, 278*278+278*278).reshape((278,278))
im = np.expand_dims(im,2)
im = np.expand_dims(im,0)

X.append( im )

print ('dim=', X.ndim, ', rows = ', X.nrows)

data.close()
```

Comment: That worked, but not getting what was problem with my code. Also can you tell me how to get the numpy array back from Earray. when I read the file it returns Earray object which on passing to matplotlib gives invalid dimensions for image error.

Comment: @Shantanu Shinde, you have A LOT of things going on in your code. When doing complicated things, start simple and add complexity. Your `data.create_earray()` call defines the atom, shape, and chunksize. Then you append the image data. All of these have to be consistent when you do this. And, when creating EArrays, you need to set one of the dimensions of the Atom instance to zero. (error message from pytables!). See 2nd answer below for coding details, along with `EArray.read()` example.